# How to use multiple Dialogflow agents in one firebase app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, service-accounts

I have multiple agents in Dialogflow and would like to connect them into a single app. However, since each agent is created in their respective GCP project, how do I connect one agent into another which I am using to run firebase hosting.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you could be looking for a feature such as [Mega Agents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-mega).
It allows you to run multiple agents under one parent agent and so combining multiple bots together in one experience.

Do note that it is a beta feature at this time, so it could be that some features changes in the future.